# Images in PDF File are distorted

Tags: applications, images, pdf

I have a PDF file, when I open it on my computer (Linux) the Images in the PDF file is displayed properly  (Its sharp)

But when I copy the same PDF from the computer to Android device and opened it there,

It looks like this

[image]

What can be the reason for this image distortion. What is the difference in opening this in computer and Android?

Any suggestions can lead me to a better search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF files are designed to maintain their content across platforms ,be immune to the application or OS

Hence, recommendation was to try alternate PDF app, which worked for OP. Adobe PDF reader used earlier was buggy, it looks like

Here's a list of [PDF readers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf), thanks to izzy